# add Formset for specific fields in a Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have a form but I want to add Formset feature specific to fields. So how can I achieve this?

model.py :

```
class somemodel(model.):
   name=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
   somefield=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
   somefield=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
   somefield=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

form.py:

```
class somemodelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=200,
         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    #I want to give Formset feature for these bellow fields

    somefield=forms.CharField(max_length=200,
         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    somefield=forms.CharField(max_length=200,
         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    somefield=forms.CharField(max_length=200,
         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model=somemodel
        fields='__all__'
```

So those are the information and I want to add Formset feature for only "somefield" fields, not to "name" field.

Comment: It's not really clear why you don't just define a form with the fields you need or don't just use a [`modelformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) specifying the fields you want to use. Alternatively, the method [`add_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset) can also be used to remove fields, just `del form.fields['name']` to remove the field.

Comment: I want to add only few fields when I press a button, not the full form.

Comment: yes it's clear what you want. I gave you three ways to do that: 1. Use a different form with only the fields you need, 2. use a modelformset_factory and specify only the fields you want 3. use your current form (but why?) and delete the fields you don't want in the add_fields method.